# What does this random string of sentences mean?

Tags: riddle, cipher

I went to my doctor a few days ago, to tell him about problems focusing, concentrating, irritableness, etc. He merely laughed and handed me a slip of paper, which had this on it:

> Veri*t*able nuns zap apples. Rig*h*t? Please, run! For fl*i*ght now, edible leeks *s*aw bees. Empathy f*i*ll*s* her. Even I validly interest - not you. Losing boys help zap nannies. l am barely grinning.<sup>1</sup> You vex Xolo. Ro*w*dy zoo, *r*ight? Zebra boys fall greatly. C*o*me round, Billy. Cats yawn. Rude questions, boys! Apples greatly quash bad zzzzs. Really. Ru*n* above bad hats to under*g*round.

When I went to ask him what it meant, he laughed again, and said, "It's your prescription, pal. Decode it and do it."

Now, as I would like to get over this, can you please help me? As I mentioned before, I'm having trubl konsintrating<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Alternative sentence: Losers are barely grinning.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>The misspelling was intentional. It does not, however, have any impact on the real question.</sub>

Comment: Before the edits come in: LEAVE BOTH CIPHER AND RIDDLE TAGS.

Comment: The italicized letters spell out "*This is Wrong*"

Comment: I don't know if this is important or not, but the "I" in "l am barely grinning" is actually a lowercase `L`, not a capital `I`.

Comment: @DooplissForce That was my most hidden hint! How'd you find it?

Comment: @Mithrandir I went to look at the source code so I could pick out all the italicized letters (which would be between asterisks), and I noticed that it was an `l`, not an `I`. Very sneaky! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The riddle is

> I am necessary for survival. You may not like me. Most people don't do me enough.

which is obtained by

> taking the first letter of each word ROT13

So your doctor is apparently telling you to

> sleep (better / more)

Comment: Very good.12345

Comment: But nope. No running.

Comment: @Mithrandir: Is the answer "eating"? It would fit the riddle, and those problems would be symptoms of not having eaten enough food recently.

Comment: @Deusovi My _next_ guess would actually be "sleep."

Comment: We're definitely treading in "too broad; guess what I'm thinking" territory though so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @Will thar's actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Starting point - Partial Answer

The italics in the message spell out:

> Thisiswrong = This is wrong

Also note that

> There is a suspiscious amount of vs, ws, xs, and zs,

Comment: So obviously the italics are *not the answer*. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir, :P yeah this is just a partia*l* answer s*o* others can continue from here if the shou*l*d do so

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I've found "lol" in your comment.